# Storyboard with Custom Buttons

Tags: xcode, storyboard

I have a storyboard setup properly with buttons leading to different scenes, however I'm not happy with how the buttons look.  They all have a perfectly square border around the images... like the images are inside a box.

Is there any way I can remove that border and simply have my image in the view, but the image still serves as a button?

Comment: Click Custom Button to hide the Button to show you Images...

Answer (score 4):

I guess what you want is to use an image as a "button".

- Select the button in storyboard
- In "attibutes inspector", select
- Button, type to "Custom", set the "background" to the image you've added to the project. 
  Should work.